# Rails using stremio-ffmpeg gem to watermark a movie while uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I am using carrierwave to upload a movie to amazon s3 that works perfect.

Now I want to add a watermark to the movie while uploading or after uploading, I don't know, what's the best way?

I tried this:

`movie_controller.rb` action uploadVideo

```
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(@vid.video.url)

puts "........................................"
puts movie.inspect

if @vid.save
```

Just to find out if the video is catched from stremio.

But then I got the error that the movie is not found, the problem is that it doesn't look in the amazon s3 bucket, it looks on my local server

```
No such file or directory - the file '/uploads/tmp/1462954331-3471-8766/VID-20160424-WA0013.mp4' does not exist
```

What could be the solution? or should I do this in carrierwave uploader?

**UPDATE:**

When I do this after the .save action it looks at amazon s3 bucket .. but also says that the movie isn't there. But if I call it directly in browser it's displayed.

**UPDATE Code:**

```
#Laedt ein Video hoch
def uploadMovie
  @user = User.find_by_id session[:user_id]
  #Holt alle Channels für die er eine Berechtigung hat (Eingeloggter user)
  @user = User.find_by_id session[:user_id]
  @knowledgeproviderList = @user.knowledgeprovider
  @channels = Channel.where(knowledgeprovider_id:     @knowledgeproviderList.pluck(:id))
  @vid = Movie.new(movies_params)
  @channel = Channel.find(params[:vid][:channel_id])
  @vid.channel = @channel

  #Fügt dem Movie einen Tag hinzu
  createTag params
  createCategory params



  if @vid.save
    flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")

    #movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(@vid.video.url)

    #puts "........................................"
    #puts movie.inspect

    redirect_to :action => :add
   else
     redirect_to :action => :add
  end
 end
```

Update error:

```
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(@vid.video.current_path)

options = {watermark: "mages/header.png", resolution: "640x360", watermark_filter: { position: "RT", padding_x: 10, padding_y: 10 } }
movie.transcode("movie.flv", options)
```

[image]

**Update:**
Added the code in the uploader:

```
  process :watermark_movie

     def watermark_movie
       if self.file.path
             options = {watermark: "images/header.png", resolution: "640x360", watermark_filter: { position: "RT", padding_x: 10, padding_y: 10 } }
             self.model.file = FFMPEG::Movie.new(self.file.path).transcode("#{root}/#{cache_dir}/#{self.cache_id}/file.mp4", options)
        end
      end
```

Error:

```
multi_json (1.12.0) lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:19:in `load'
multi_json (1.12.0) lib/multi_json.rb:122:in `load'
streamio-ffmpeg (2.0.0) lib/ffmpeg/movie.rb:28:in `initialize'
app/uploaders/movie_uploader.rb:40:in `new'
app/uploaders/movie_uploader.rb:40:in `watermark_movie'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:84:in `block in process!'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `each'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `process!'
carrierwave_backgrounder (0.4.2) lib/backgrounder/delay.rb:14:in `process!'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:134:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:329:in `cache'
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:163:in `video='
carrierwave (0.11.2) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:39:in `video='
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:183:in `each_pair'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:559:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:71:in `uploadMovie'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/home/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**UPDATE -- Movie Uploader**

```
# encoding: utf-8
class MovieUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer
  include CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  require 'rubygems'
  require 'streamio-ffmpeg'

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process :watermark_movie

  def watermark_movie
    puts "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
    puts self.file.inspect

    if self.file.path
      options = {watermark: "http://felix-hohlwegler.de/holz-soft/include/designs/design13/images/header.png", resolution: "640x360", watermark_filter: { position: "RT", padding_x: 10, padding_y: 10 } }
      self.model.file = FFMPEG::Movie.new(self.file.path).transcode("#{root}/#{cache_dir}/#{self.cache_id}/file.mp4", options)
    end
  end

  version :thumb do
    process thumbnail: [{format: 'png', quality: 10, size: 1200, strip: false, seek: 10, logger: Rails.logger}]
    def full_filename for_file
      png_name for_file, version_name
    end
  end

  def png_name for_file, version_name
    %Q{#{version_name}_#{for_file.chomp(File.extname(for_file))}.png}
  end


  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_white_list
     %w(mov avi mkv mpeg mpeg2 mp4 3gp)
   end
end
```

Comment: Based on your error, it happens inside MultiJson [here](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json/blob/master/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb#L19) because of empty string passed to load method after calling by streamio-ffmpeg from [here](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/ffmpeg/movie.rb#L28). String is resulted std_output of the following statement (line #17): command = "#{FFMPEG.ffprobe_binary} -i #{Shellwords.escape(path)} -print_format json -show_format -show_streams -show_error" - can you run this command manually in console (terminal) and see what it outputs?

Comment: For ffprobe_binary check [here](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg/blob/32f68006222b293d8b9482616a7e79d63fe97829/lib/streamio-ffmpeg.rb) - do you have it properly available?

Comment: Unless you set it manually, the code is "def self.ffprobe_binary;   @ ffprobe_binary || which('ffprobe');  end"

Comment: Also, what would be self.file.path value that is passed to streamio-ffmpeg? By the way, it doesn't look like ffprobe_binary would work with URLs, so you definitely need a local file full path+filename (at least looking [here](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg) - movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("path/to/movie.mov")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Kyle together we figured out that the following is required

only version 1.0.0 works fine

```
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg', '1.0.0'
```

The function is now in the carrierwave uploader and looks like this:

```
  process :watermark_movie

  def watermark_movie
      options = {watermark: "#{Rails.root}/public/images/logo_klein.png", resolution: "640x360", watermark_filter: {position: "RT", padding_x: 10, padding_y: 10},custom: '-strict experimental'}
      #debugger
      tmp_path = File.join File.dirname(current_path), "tmp_file.mp4"
      file = FFMPEG::Movie.new(self.file.path)
      file.transcode tmp_path, options
      File.rename tmp_path, current_path
  end
```

At the Moment there are no more errors, problem is still that the watermark is not working.

Update:

A working solution is:

```
system "ffmpeg -i #{self.file.path} -vf 'movie=#{watermarkimage} [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]' -strict experimental #{tmp_path}"
```

Comment: so you need streamio-ffmpeg gem in order to watermark a carrierwave video?

Answer (score 4):

We do something similar in our application that deals with audio. Obviously, we do not use video or watermarking but we use streamio-ffmpeg to do some transcoding of sorts.

Instead of doing code in the controller related to the watermark, why not instead move that functionality to the uploader. For example, our `convert_to_mp3` method could be your watermarking method. Seems like this would potentially solve your problem.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  before :store, :remember_cache_id
  after :store, :delete_tmp_dir

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  process :convert_to_mp3

  def convert_to_mp3
    if self.file.path
      if self.file.extension == 'm4a' || self.file.extension == 'wav' || self.file.extension == 'aac'
        self.model.file = FFMPEG::Movie.new(self.file.path).transcode("#{root}/#{cache_dir}/#{self.cache_id}/file.mp3", options_string)
      end
    end
  end

  def options_string
    if self.file.extension == 'm4a'
      "-acodec libmp3lame -write_xing 0"
    elsif self.file.extension == 'aac'
      "-acodec libmp3lame -write_xing 0"
    elsif self.file.extension == 'wav'
      "-acodec libmp3lame -write_xing 0"
    end
  end


  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(mp3 m4a wav)
  end

  def cache_id
    @cache_id
  end

  def remember_cache_id(new_file)
    @cache_id_was = cache_id
  end

  def delete_tmp_dir(new_file)
    # make sure we don't delete other things accidentally by checking the name pattern
    if @cache_id_was.present? && @cache_id_was =~ /\A[\d]{8}\-[\d]{4}\-[\d]+\-[\d]{4}\z/
      FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join(root, cache_dir, @cache_id_was))
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: That looks great I gonna test this todays evening. Thanks

Comment: I mean it looks like a general JSON parse error. What is the value of self.file and self.file.path?

Comment: tried this:  puts self.file.path.inspect -- and got the same error

Comment: what about puts self.file.inspect ?

Comment: returns this: 
"/var/www/ji_bildungsplattform/public/uploads/tmp/1464791840-5971-0003-5475/VID-20160424-WA0013.mp4"

Comment: Is carrierwave configured correctly? Do you have any carrierwave additional gem that may be causing an issue? It doesn't look like the streamio-ffmpeg gem. Or more importantly, is the data being uploaded causing invalid json?

Comment: it works perfectly unti I add the stremio-ffmpeg functions. I'm using those gems for carrierwave:   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer
  include CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

Comment: I've added the uploader source above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113552/discussion-between-kyle-and-felix).

Comment: Sorry I hade some courses at university today I'm at home just now. do you have time for me?

Answer (score 3):

From the CarrierWave docs:

> CarrierWave gives you a store for permanent storage, and a cache for temporary storage. You can use different stores, including filesystem and cloud storage.

and

> ...you can cache files by assigning to the attribute, they will automatically be stored when the record is saved.

Assuming that you've mounted your uploader to the `video` column of your model, (e.g - `mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader`) calling `video.url` will return the cache path after you *assign* a value to `video` column.  After you save the model, the `url` method will look in the store path.

In your case, calling `@vid.video.store_path` will tell ffmpeg to look at your S3 bucket - however, it's best to [familiarize yourself with the cache and store path](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/frames#Getting_Started), because watermarking may be more performant on the local, cached version of the file.

---

Comment: Is then a possibility to first watermark the movie and upload it afterwards?

Comment: I'm not sure what library/tool you're using to watermark, but I would assume you could perform whatever task you need on the cached version of the file, meaning, perform some task synchronously _before_ calling `@vid.save`.  Once you call `.save`, CarrierWave will perform an upload of whatever file you've linked to the model via the `video` column.

Comment: how can I do this: perform some task synchronously before calling @vid.save

Comment: Can you post the full uploadVideo action in movie_controller.rb?

Comment: Try this before calling `@vid.save`, as you did your initial post: `movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(@vid.video.current_path)`

Your initial problem was likely caused by providing an incomplete path to the FFMPEG::Movie initializer.  Once you confirm that this works with `.current_path` instead of `.url`, you should be able to watermark, call `@vid.save`, and see the changes reflected in the file uploaded to S3.

Comment: tried it with your suggestion of current_path. I got an JSON::ParserError

I add the code above

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of that error from your server logs?  The above screenshot does not suggest whether this is a rails rendering error or a stremio-ffmpeg error.

Also, you may have a typo here: options = {watermark: "mages/header.png",...

Comment: No I have the full qualified path here with my website domain. I have added the full stack trace above.

Comment: Don't include your website domain here - specify an absolute path to where the watermark png is on your server.

Comment: if `self.file.inspect` is the string file path, what happens if you swap all references to `self.file.path` with `self.file.inspect`?

Comment: It returns this:  
returns this: "/var/www/ji_bildungsplattform/public/uploads/tmp/1464791840-5971-0003-5475/VID-‌​20160424-WA0013.mp4"

Comment: oh okay I got what you mean ... sorry I try it

Comment: Chaged to self.file.inspect? ... and changed the url to image to a path on the server ... publics/images ... But got same error as well